# saving item to key chain gets not found error

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

When I save items to the keychain I get a success but after fetching it I get an error not found.

```
enum KeychainError: Error {
case itemNotFound
case duplicateItem
case invalidItemFormat
case unexpectedStatus(OSStatus)
}

final class KeyChainManager {
    
    static let service = "www.test.de"

    
static func save(password: String, account: String) throws {

    let passwordData = password.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let query: [String: Any] = [
        kSecClass as String: kSecClassInternetPassword,
        kSecAttrAccount as String: account,
        kSecAttrServer as String: service,
        kSecValueData as String: passwordData
    ]

    let status = SecItemAdd(
        query as CFDictionary,
        nil
    )

    if status == errSecDuplicateItem {
        throw KeychainError.duplicateItem
    }
    guard status == errSecSuccess else {
        throw KeychainError.unexpectedStatus(status)
    }
    print("success")
}

static func readPassword( account: String) throws -> Data {
    let query: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrService as String: service as AnyObject,
        kSecAttrAccount as String: account as AnyObject,
        kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne,
        kSecReturnData as String: kCFBooleanTrue
    ]

    var itemCopy: AnyObject?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(
        query as CFDictionary,
        &itemCopy
    )

    guard status != errSecItemNotFound else {
        throw KeychainError.itemNotFound
    }
    

    guard status == errSecSuccess else {
        throw KeychainError.unexpectedStatus(status)
    }

    guard let password = itemCopy as? Data else {
        throw KeychainError.invalidItemFormat
    }

    return password
  }
}
```

If I try

```
try KeyChainManager.save(password: input.password ?? "", account: input.username ?? "")
```

I get success but if I try to load the password it stops on this line
throw KeychainError.itemNotFound

Comment: You save *InternetPassword* but you load *GenericPassword*. I would use the same type

Comment: thanks for that. I now dont get unknown found but status error 25303. whatever that means however its at least some progress

Comment: @user1898829 `-25303` indicates an invalid attribute aka `errSecNoSuchAttr`